# Javascript Cookies On android

Tags: javascript, cookies

I've done a lot of research on this question, but every method on the internet won't help...

How to create a JavaScript (function) that basically does the following:
Take the value of input "a" as a cookie "name".
Take the value of input "b" as cookie "content/value".
Take the value of input "c" as the time the cookie needs to expire in.
Save this data as a cookie.

```
<input type="text" id="a" placeholder="name" />
...
```

And another function that allows you to display the cookies
(figured this one out myself :P)

```
function show() {
   var d=document.cookie;
   alert(d);
}
```

Comment: Please read this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp in addition to your great research. J

Comment: I did. This method only returns me a blank alert window, no cookies are displayed. Not in chrome, not in the standard browser. Any tips?

Comment: Please post the code in which you set cookie and then get cookie.

Comment: I'll edit the code in the question. I'll let you know here when I'm done.